# Swing: resize icon to fit text with specified font in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel

I'm trying to create two JLabels - one for icon (*UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon")* - one of Java's standart icons) and one for text. Sure, I know there is a JLabel's constructor which can make one label from icon and text, but I need exactly two labels, because one of them should be highlighted when mouse moves through it, I omit this part of code.

The problem is I can't find out how to change Icon size. At least I want to set manually height of icon, but it would be better if its height calculated automatically to fit text with specified font. I spent several hours trying to find information in the Web, but couldn't find anything relative.
I tried to implement Icon class and override getIconHeight() and getIconWidth() methods, but I don't know what to do next with my Icon object, because Icon is an interface so it has no constructors.

Here is my simplified code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class AppView
{
    private final JFrame main_frame;

    public AppView()
    {
        main_frame = new JFrame();
        main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main_frame.setTitle("Example");

        JPanel main_panel = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Dimension getPreferredSize()
            {
                return new Dimension(200,  200);
            }
        };

        main_frame.getContentPane().add(main_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main_panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());

        JLabel label_icon = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
        JLabel label_text = new JLabel("Text goes here");
        label_text.setFont(new Font("sans-serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        main_panel.add(label_icon);
        main_panel.add(label_text);

        main_frame.pack();
        main_frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new AppView();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the result, as you can see, Icon is higher than text:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I predict less than satisfactory results if you try to squash those icons down to the height of the text.  I recommend not resizing them at all.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
If I use JTree and change font size of node's text, icon is resized automatically to fit text height.

Comment: So what?  If those icons are dynamically generated, they can easily be scaled up or down.  It is much harder to retain quality when scaling a (fixed size) image.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
So you think the only way to solve this problem is to save required images to my computer, resize them with some image editor and after that use them in code?

Comment: BTW - *"use JTree and change font size of node's text, icon is resized automatically to fit text height"*  No it isn't.  Not according to my quick test.  Can you provide code that shows it resizing?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
Sorry, it seems that I misinformed you. I tested with 14 and 18 points font and thought that image was resized, but now I set 30 points and saw that image wasn't resized at all. Anyway, do you know how can I get these standard icons? I couldn't find any archive with them on the Internet and I also don't know, whether I can save icons directly to my computer using Java.

Comment: *"So you think the only way to solve this problem is to save required images to my computer, resize them with some image editor and after that use them in code?"*  That is less optimal than (for example), having a way to draw them dynamically, and doing that instead.  It seems those symbols could be replicated using a character ('i', '!', '?') inside a color filled shape (circle, triangle, octagon).